# Adding a favicon to a website

Tags: html, favicon

I added a icon to a site I built but the problem is it doesn't appear on Google Chrome And Safari. And here's what I did:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="icon/icon" href= Jo.ico />
<title>My site</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It can take days sometimes for them to appear. Whenever I have issues with my favicon not showing up, I browse to it directly in the browser and force a reload.

Comment: Have you tried clearing up the browser's cache? Sometimes that does the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your icon to the root folder of your website with the name: favicon.ico

Answer (score 2):

Well you haven't put speech marks on the href section. And also, you should give your content a more unique identifier, because text and html are keywords, so the browser may, hypothetically, misinterpret them.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try this instead:

```
<link href="Jo.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
```

Your browsers may also be caching the icon. Please make sure your browser cache is properly cleared.

Also, make sure the icon's path is correct ("Jo.ico" assumes the icon is in the same directory as the file containing the above line of HTML).

Comment: You can also browse to the icon within the site and refresh to force it to load :)

Comment: Indeed, this will refresh the cached version of the icon. Sometimes hitting ctrl+f5 is still necessary when you're back on the page though.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

HTML 4.01:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
```

XHTM 1.0:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
```

**Method 2**

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Apple Devices:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
```

**Method 3**

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

**Methond 4** (no support at the moment)

HTML 5:

```
<link rel="icon" href="demo_icon.gif" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16" />
```